# Mockito- mock field in class

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I have got a question connected with Mockito framework. Is there any way to mock a field inside a class? Lets say we have got:

```java
@Component
public class A{
    @Autowired
    B b;

    public methodExample(){b.doSth();}
}


class C {
    @Autowired
    A a;
}

@Test
    public void testMethodExample(){...}
}
```

Is there any possibility to mock B object in order to impose return value of method doSth? I know I can pass mocked object as an argument of constructor but I wonder if there is any other option?

Comment: This is exactly what the @InjectMocks annotation is for.  Willian got this one right!

Answer (score 4):

You may take a look at [@InjectMocks](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html).
With this annotation Mockito will try to assign the mocks through constructor, property and field, respectively, stopping at the first approach which succeeds.
Thus a unit test for your scenario might look like:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith( MockitoJUnitRunner.class )
public class c
{

    @InjectMocks
    A a;

    @Mock
    B b;

    @Test
    public void testMethodExample()
    {
        a.methodExample();
    }
}
```

Some points worth some attention:

- `@InjectMocks` will only take into account the *fields* annotated with `@Mock`
- It's necessary to use `MockitoJUnitRunner`OR call `org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in order to create and inject your mocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a protected setter for testing only and have your test package structure mirror the package structure of your main code.

Or you can use the Powermock extension to mock private/protected fields as required.

See

https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething(){
    A a = new A();
    B mockedB = //create a mock;

    Whitebox.setInternalState(a, "b", mockedB);
}
```